# celery issue while running periodic task via admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I have setup celery on my server and tasks are running fine if we send them by command line but from admin dashboard the task hits are not coming in the celery worker logs. How can we fix it?

i tried to run a periodic task from the admin dashboard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.